# FORTRAN input from mouse

Tags: input, fortran, mouse

What is the FORTRAN input statement (e.g., READ statement, or OPEN statement) to accept input from a mouse? For example, in Windows explorer, it is possible to right-click on a file and then select a FORTRAN executable from the menu that appears. How do I make such a FORTRAN program capture whatever the mouse sends (e.g., capture the name of the file, or whatever the mouse transmits)? Information out there about FORTRAN input seems restricted to input from a file or the keyboard. I cannot find anything about input from a mouse.

Comment: If your question ever starts out _"Can anyone give me code to..."_ it probably doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: As @MattBall said - SO is not a place to get someone else to write your code. Try something yourself, and when you're stuck, post a well-written description of the problem you ran into. Just asking for stock code isn't welcome here.

Comment: It really depends on which compiler you are using.  Windows toolchains like IVF and Silverfrost have a GUI interface: just read the documentation.  In fact, using IVF, you can write Windows SDK type programs.  Silverfrost is similar but a bit cryptic.

Comment: I'm using the latest gfortran compiler.

Comment: Look into SDL (http://www.libsdl.org/) for getting access to mouse events, then write Fortran interfaces to desired routines using `ISO_C_BINDING`.

Comment: The mouse **never** sends the name of the file...

Answer (score 0):

I've made progress on my own and, for those interested, here it is:
Firstly, the "fortran standard" does not directly support input from a mouse. But Windows Explorer can be made to pipe a file name into a fortran executable nevetheless.

Under Windows, the right-click generates the full \path\filename as a command line argument. That information can be captured by a fortran using "get_command_argument", as follows:

```
      PROGRAM get_filename
        CHARACTER(len=100) :: arg
        CHARACTER(len=2000) :: filename
        filename = ''
        ! NB: spaces in a file name define separate arguments, so re-assemble the file name as it comes in
        i = 1
        DO
         CALL get_command_argument(i, arg)
          IF (LEN_TRIM(arg) == 0) EXIT
          filename = TRIM(filename)//' '//TRIM(arg) !  putting the spaces back in
          i = i+1
        END DO
        WRITE (*,*) 'file= ',TRIM(filename)
      read(*,*)
      END PROGRAM
```

A link to the executable can be placed in the Windows right-click menu, as explained here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

You need to add "%1" to the name of the executable to make it accept command line arguments,
e.g., I called my executable "PW_copy.exe", and so the final registry entry was: \path\PW_copy.exe %1

It works!

Dragging the mouse across several files generates separate threads each with a different file name.